# Is it possbile to bridge CDI Event to JAXRS SSE in CDI2/JAXRS 2.1/Java EE8?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs, cdi, server-sent-events, weld

The SSE in jersey is standardized in JAXRS 2.1 finally, I have tried the SSE features.

I think it could be used in the following scenarios.

- Client user click some links, and server receives it and send some notification to client.
- The server itself send some messages to client, such as some batch job is done etc.

What I think is use CDI event to handle domain events, and see if possible use `@Observes` a CDI event and send it to client via SSE.

Some codes I have written to try it.

The message payload class.

```
public class Message implements Serializable {

    private String body;

    public Message() {
    }

    public Message(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

}
```

A rest resource for sending messages.

```
@Path("mesages")
@RequestScoped
public class MessageResource {

    @Inject
    Event<Message> messageEvent;

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response send(Message message) {
        messageEvent.fire(message);
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
}
```

I tried to add CDI `@Observes` in SSE resource method, **but it will application startup failure**.

```
@Path("cdievents")
@RequestScoped
public class SseCdiResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
    public void eventStreamCdi(@Context Sse sse, @Context SseEventSink eventSink, @Observes Message msg) {
        eventSink.send(
                sse.newEventBuilder()
                        .mediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                        .id(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                        .name("message from cdi")
                        .data(msg)
                        .build()
        );
    }

}
```

BTW: I am using Glassfish v5, the complete codes is [here](https://github.com/hantsy/ee8-sandbox/tree/master/jaxrs-sse).

**Update**: Just tried `SseBroadcaster`, it works with CDI event.

```
@Path("broadcastEvents")
@Singleton
public class BroadcastResource {

    @Context
    private Sse sse;

    private volatile SseBroadcaster sseBroadcaster;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.sseBroadcaster = sse.newBroadcaster();
    }

    @GET
    //@Path("register")
    @Produces(MediaType.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
    public void register(@Context SseEventSink eventSink) {
        eventSink.send(sse.newEvent("welcome!"));
        sseBroadcaster.register(eventSink);
    }

    @POST
    //@Path("broadcast")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    public void broadcast(@FormParam("event") String event) {
        sseBroadcaster.broadcast(sse.newEvent(event));
    }

    public void eventStreamCdi(@Observes Message msg) {
        sseBroadcaster.broadcast(
                sse.newEventBuilder()
                        .mediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                        .id(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                        .name("message from cdi")
                        .data(msg)
                        .build()
        );
    }
}
```

But how to get it work with the single `SseEventSink` as the first case?

Comment: `SseEventSink` is only valid for a given request.  So the only way to do that is to propagate the sink with your event to be processed.

Comment: @JohnAment Yes, if I add an extra CDI bean to pool the eventsink, it works. I have updated [my codes](https://github.com/hantsy/ee8-sandbox/tree/master/jaxrs-sse). And it behaves a little like `SseBroadcaster `.